# Getting a resized image from an UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift

I need to upload image data to my `Parse.com` backend, but I found out that my pictures are way too big, dimensions wise. NSHipster had an article on image resizing with this code:

```
import ImageIO

if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(self.URL, nil) {
    let options: CFDictionary = [
        kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize: max(size.width, size.height) / 2.0,
        kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageIfAbsent: true
    ]

    let scaledImage = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(imageSource, 0, options).flatMap { UIImage(CGImage: $0) }
}
```

Unfortunately, this code does not compile in Swift 1.2. In particular there are 2 problems. The `CFDictionary` could not be initialized, and `flatMap` method was not recognized.

Comment: I can write the Objective c equivalent to resize image according to imageview code if that helps in any way

Comment: Thanks for the offer. I think the answer below will suffice, but I am still very interested in getting the above code to work.

Comment: sure, yes it does , accept the answer if it helps :)

Comment: @SahebRoy You cannot accept an answer until 10 minute after you asked the question. But will accept now!

Comment: do you still want your code working? @KelvinLau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some functions for resize your image:

```
import UIKit

func RBSquareImageTo(image: UIImage, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    return RBResizeImage(RBSquareImage(image), size)
}

func RBSquareImage(image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    var originalWidth  = image.size.width
    var originalHeight = image.size.height

    var edge: CGFloat
    if originalWidth > originalHeight {
        edge = originalHeight
    } else {
        edge = originalWidth
    }

    var posX = (originalWidth  - edge) / 2.0
    var posY = (originalHeight - edge) / 2.0

    var cropSquare = CGRectMake(posX, posY, edge, edge)

    var imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, cropSquare);
    return UIImage(CGImage: imageRef, scale: UIScreen.mainScreen().scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)
}

func RBResizeImage(image: UIImage, targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let size = image.size

    let widthRatio  = targetSize.width  / image.size.width
    let heightRatio = targetSize.height / image.size.height

    // Figure out what our orientation is, and use that to form the rectangle
    var newSize: CGSize
    if(widthRatio > heightRatio) {
        newSize = CGSizeMake(size.width * heightRatio, size.height * heightRatio)
    } else {
        newSize = CGSizeMake(size.width * widthRatio,  size.height * widthRatio)
    }

    // This is the rect that we've calculated out and this is what is actually used below
    let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)

    // Actually do the resizing to the rect using the ImageContext stuff
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
    image.drawInRect(rect)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
```

From [HERE](https://gist.github.com/hcatlin/180e81cd961573e3c54d).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Objective C code that scale the image given by parameters.

```
-(UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image
              scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```